# Как организовать передачу данных между процессами через разделяемую память?

Tags: c++, winapi, процесс

Условия взяты из задания к лабораторной работе. Нужно передавать данные между процессами с помощью разделяемой памяти средствами Win API. В википедии указано, что в windows используется либо `CreateSharedMemory`, либо проецирование с помощью `CreateFileMapping`, так как примеров для первого случая я не нашел, решил воспользоваться вторым вариантом. И вот, собственно, код проецирования в родительском процессе

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\spark\\source\\repos\\Lab3SRV\\data.txt", 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nullptr,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);

HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, BUF_SIZE, szName);

unsigned char* pBuf = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

Код проецирования из дочернего процесса

```
hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, szName);
    unsigned char* pBuf = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

Я не совсем понял, что не понравилось преподавателю. Он сказал, что я не должен использовать файл

```
"C:\\Users\\spark\\source\\repos\\Lab3SRV\\data.txt"
```

Исходя из задания, мне он и не особо нужен, так как никаких исходных данных там нет, может мне стоит просто записать в параметр hFile `CreateFileMapping` 0xFFFFFFFF, тогда будет использоваться безымянный буфер из памяти?
Либо он имел в виду другой способ реализации разделяемой памяти?
Вопрос в том, соответствует ли мой код условию задачи или мне нужно было пользоваться чем-то другим? Например, `CreateSharedMemory`.

Comment: Функции семейства `CreateSharedMemory` (несмотря на название) предназначены для использования только в контексте аутентификации windows. Так что использовать их не стоит. *"Я не совсем понял, что не понравилось преподавателю."* - ну так это надо у него уточнять. А вообще да, файл не нужн, в windows можно использовать неименованную разделяемую память.

Comment: @vtt просто он особо и не всматривался в код, и я подумал, что он увидел то, что я файл передаю, и сделал вывод, что я пишу/читаю посредством writefile/readfile. Не знаю, моя ошибка, что я у него лишний раз не уточнил. Спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове `CreateFileMapping` первым аргументом укажите `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, а в параметрах `dwMaximumSizeHigh` и `dwMaximumSizeLow` задайте размер разделяемой памяти. В этом случае в качестве разделяемого файла будет использоваться страничный файл системы (pagefile.sys).

Цитата из описания функции `CreateFileMapping`:

> If hFile is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, the calling process must also
>   specify a size for the file mapping object in the dwMaximumSizeHigh
>   and dwMaximumSizeLow parameters. In this scenario, CreateFileMapping
>   creates a file mapping object of a specified size that is backed by
>   the system paging file instead of by a file in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

В целом ваше решение рабочее.

Но преподаватель прав в том, что создавать файл совершенно лишнее. Для вашей задачи вы можете создать отображение указав невалидный хендл файла, вот так:

```
HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, ...);
```

Как [пишет MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga):

> Если аргумент `hFile` равен `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` вызвающий процесс должен обязательно указать размер отображения файла в аргументах `dwMaximumSizeHigh` и `dwMaximumSizeLow`. В этом случае функция `CreateFileMapping` создаст объект отображения файла указанного отображения с использованием ресурсов файла подкачки, вместо файла на диске.